# Прервать другую go-рутину

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Вот есть некая функция `f() {for true {}}`
Которая вызывается из программы в отдельный поток: `go f()`
Как при повторном вызове `go f()` прервать выполняющуюся.
Подробный пример:

```
func main(){    
go getRedisBD()

time.Sleep(time.Duration(10)*time.Minute)
go getRedisBD()
}

func getRedisBD{
time.Sleep(time.Duration(3)*time.Minute)
getRedisBD()
}
```

И вот спустя 10 минут, нужно удалить данную функцию с потока и запустить заного.

Comment: Обычный семафор, не?

Comment: @D-side: Если нужно не дождаться окончания, а просто проверить, подошёл бы и простой флаг возможно, с синхронизацией).

Comment: @VladD тьфу, семафор же предполагает ожидание. Да, там достаточно просто атомарного флага.

Comment: Мне нужно прервать выполнение данного потока

Comment: Ну, когда заходите в цикл, проверяете, не задан ли некий атомарный флаг. Если не задан, устанавливаете и начинаете цикл. Если задан -- проходите мимо.

Comment: Да мне обновить надо функцию, то есть сначала закрыть тот поток, а потом открыть заного

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример того, что у вас есть и добавьте в вопрос точное описание того, что хотите сделать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прервать горутину снаружи нельзя.

Вы можете выставлять какой-то флаг и проверять его внутри функции или передать канал в качестве параметра и записать туда значение, когда потребуется функцию прервать.

Но проверять что флаг, что канал должна та горутина, которую нужно остановить. Только она сама может завершить своё выполнение.

Исключение - os.Exit(...), но тогда останавливается вся программа сразу, никакие defer, финализаторы и т.п. не вызываются.

т.е.

```
func f(){
for {}
}
```

вы остановить никак не сможете без завершения программы целиком.

Можно сделать что-то вроде

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    flag := false
    go f(&flag)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    flag = true
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(2)

}

func f(flag *bool) {
    for {
        if *flag {
            fmt.Println(1)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Или так:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    stop := make(chan bool)
    go f(stop)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    stop <- true
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(2)

}

func f(stop chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println(1)
            return
        default:
            // Ветка default нужна, чтобы при отсутствии сообщений в chan работа функции продолжилась вместо блокировки на ожидании сообщения
        }
    }

}
```